# Would it be possible to copy files from a existing webapp folder to another webapp folder

Tags: powershell, azure, msbuild, storage

I am trying to copy a webapp folder as-is to another webapp folder on Azure using powershell. Or, Copy the folder from the storage account to quick created webapp folder?

Hope someone worked on this route before? I read through Azure & Powershell documentation but could find upload and download or other basic operations only but not moving from storage account to webapp folder.

Thanking in advance for sharing pointers or similiar article.

Regards

H Bala

Comment: I am at this point going this route. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-web-arm-from-github-provision/ Hope it is the right approach.

Comment: If you want to clone a web app, check the article [Azure App Service App Cloning Using Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-cloning-portal/).